# Can I update an ongoing d3 transition on drag

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3 to add lat/lon points on to a geographical projection. I've also implemented some drag controls to rotate the sphere.

I'd like to have a transition which adds the points sequentially, but if I drag the sphere to move it during the transition, things start to go wrong: I think its because the transition endpoint is being set before any rotation happens - the points seem to tween to where they would be if no rotation had occurred.

If I then rotate the sphere after they have appeared they snap to where they should be (as per the update function).

Does anyone know how to sort this? Can you effectively do the append after the delay i.e. add and transition the points in one go, before adding the next point. Or perhaps there is some way of updating the transition in the ondrag function.

My example code is in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4698qjx5/)

```
leeroyjenkins = function(){
    var data = [{"lat": 0, "lon": 0},
                {"lat": 10, "lon": 10},
                {"lat": 20, "lon": 20},
                {"lat": 30, "lon": 30},
                {"lat": 40, "lon": 40},]
    main(data);
};

var main = function(points) {
  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
      .scale(250)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
      .clipAngle(90);

  var pointpath = function(d, r) {
              var pr = d3.geo.path().projection(projection).pointRadius(r);
              return pr({type: "Point", coordinates: [d.lon, d.lat]})
            }

  var λ = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([-180, 180]);

  var φ = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([90, -90]);

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function() { var r = projection.rotate();
                          return {x: λ.invert(r[0]), y: φ.invert(r[1])}; })
      .on("drag", function() {
        projection.rotate([λ(d3.event.x), φ(d3.event.y)]);
        svg.selectAll("path.point").attr("d", function(d) {return pointpath(d, 10)});
      });

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                  .append("div") 
                  .attr("id", "tooltip");

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(drag);

  svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "outline")
        .datum({type: "Sphere"})
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection));

  var point = svg.selectAll("path.point").data(points);
  point.enter()
        .append("path")
          .attr("class", "point")
          .attr("d", function(d) {return pointpath(d, 0)})
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i){return i * 1000;})
            .duration(500)
            .attr("d", function(d) {return pointpath(d, 10)});
};

leeroyjenkins();
```

Comment: You could add a new transition to the updated position on rotate.

Answer (score 0):

the fiddle should be updated with a solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4698qjx5/1/). Basically, I did an attribute tween and set the interpolated radius as a property of that data point - this is then accessed in the update function. Does that seem like an optimal solution?

```
leeroyjenkins = function(){
    var data = [{"lat": 0, "lon": 0},
                {"lat": 10, "lon": 10},
                {"lat": 20, "lon": 20},
                {"lat": 30, "lon": 30},
                {"lat": 40, "lon": 40},]
    main(data);
};

var main = function(points) {
  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var projection = d3.geo.orthographic()
      .scale(250)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
      .clipAngle(90);

  var pointpath = function(d, r) {
              var pr = d3.geo.path().projection(projection).pointRadius(r);
              return pr({type: "Point", coordinates: [d.lon, d.lat]})
            }

  var λ = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, width])
      .range([-180, 180]);

  var φ = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, height])
      .range([90, -90]);

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function() { var r = projection.rotate();
                          return {x: λ.invert(r[0]), y: φ.invert(r[1])}; })
      .on("drag", function() {
        projection.rotate([λ(d3.event.x), φ(d3.event.y)]);
        svg.selectAll("path.point").attr("d", function(d) {return pointpath(d, d.r)});
      });

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                  .append("div") 
                  .attr("id", "tooltip");

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(drag);

  svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "outline")
        .datum({type: "Sphere"})
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection));

  var point = svg.selectAll("path.point").data(points);
  point.enter()
        .append("path")
          .attr("class", "point")
          .attr("d", function(d) {return pointpath(d, 0)})
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d, i){return i * 1000;})
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                rinterp = d3.interpolate(0, 10);
                var fn = function(t) {
                  d.r = rinterp(t);
                  return pointpath(d, d.r);
                };
                return fn;
            });
};

leeroyjenkins();
```